# Getting bad results when testing my prediction model on new patients

Tags: classification, random-forest, unbalanced-classes, overfitting, adaboost

I analyze medical diagnostic labeled data: the independent variables are medical parameters (assume that one of the variables is blood pressure) and the dependent variable is 1 or 0. The data contains just 4 features.
the medical diagnostic duration is a few hours so each patient has dozens of records.
my data contains less than 10  patients.

When I split my current patients data to 20/80 test training/test data I get great results (I'm checking recall and precision metrics).

But when I'm checking the model on a new patient that the model doesn't know the metrics results are very bad.

I have tried many classifications models: logistic regression(checked both L1 and L2), random forest, GBM, SVM, and AdaBoost.

In addition, the data is unbalanced and I also tried SMOOTH.

I assume that my model is overfitting.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: A 20/80 split of ten patients is fitting a model on just *eight* people and testing only against two, right?  Whether you get great results or not, don't you think this might be too few data to generalize reliably?

Comment: You are right and I asked for more data, but right now this is my data and I'm trying to get the best from it.